# Trouble with `sequelize-typescript` many to many assocations

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have been struggling with setting up a many-to-many association using `sequelize-typescript` I feel like I have gone through every post that covers this (there are not many) and I have followed the documentation as close as I can and I cannot get it working.

I have the following models: `User`, `Vehicle`, & `UserVehicle`

`User.model.ts`

```
@Table({
  tableName: 'users'
})
class User extends Model {
  @Column({
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataType.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4
  })
  id!: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isUrl: true,
      len: [0, 2083]
    }
  })
  email!: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  })
  name!: string | null;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  })
  picture!: string | null;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    field: 'remote_id'
  })
  remoteId!: string;

  @Column({
    field: 'created_at'
  })
  @CreatedAt
  createdAt!: Date;

  @Column({
    field: 'updated_at'
  })
  @UpdatedAt
  updatedAt!: Date;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Vehicle, () => UserVehicle)
  vehicles!: Vehicle[];
}

export default User;
```

`Vehicle.model.ts`

```
@Table({
  tableName: 'vehicles'
})
class Vehicle extends Model {
  @Column({
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataType.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4
  })
  id!: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  })
  make!: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  })
  model!: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.DECIMAL,
    allowNull: true
  })
  odometer!: number | null;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.DECIMAL,
    allowNull: true
  })
  year!: number | null;

  @Column({
    field: 'created_at'
  })
  @CreatedAt
  createdAt!: Date;

  @Column({
    field: 'updated_at'
  })
  @UpdatedAt
  updatedAt!: Date;

  @BelongsToMany(() => User, () => UserVehicle)
  users!: User[];
}

export default Vehicle;
```

`UserVehicle.model.ts`

```
@Table({
  tableName: 'user_vehicles',
  timestamps: false
})
class UserVehicle extends Model implements UserVehicle {
  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    field: 'user_id'
  })
  userId!: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Vehicle)
  @Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    field: 'vehicle_id',
  })
  vehicleId!: string;

}

export default UserVehicle;
```

whenever I do something like `user.vehicles` (where user is an actual user) I get undefined & I do not see any SQL being executed. I have no idea what I have to do at this point. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Show a query you are trying to execute

Comment: @Anatoly So it looks like I can query it by doing something like: `user.$get('vehicles')` but what I was trying to do was `user.vehicles`. I am not sure why I have to use that `gettter`? and I don't really see any documentation on that. I also don't know how to get the associated data out of the `user.$get('vehicles')` response since that retrieves the `Vehicle` objects associated w/ the current user but also each `UserVehicle` too which I can't figure out how to filter out?